# how to handle enabling/disabling bluetooth in onResume function in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am coding an android app to manage and control my own smart devices, which will connect through BLE to the app.

I am really new to this, so far I managed to create a button called "ADD DEVICE" that redirects me to the ScanningForDevicesActivity, which is an activity responsible for scanning BLE devices and displaying the list of discovered devices (to do yet).

This is the flow of responsivity I want to achieve:
-> press ADD DEVICE and go to ScanningForDevicesActivity
-> if bluetooth is not enabled -> ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE
-> if request is DENIED (result code: RESULT_CANCELED) then go back to MainActivity
-> if bluetooth was enabled and then externally disabled (from the phone) while app is being active, then prompt intent ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE

Suppose that I enable bluetooth upon request, and then I disable it but from the phone (not my app) I want the app to ask for REQUEST_BLUETOOTH_ENABLE again if I'm on the ScanningForDevicesActivity.

The issue is that, if I place this code on the onResume function for this current activity, since this function runs periodically, the request for enabling bluetooth is repeated, meaning I have to press twice DENY or ACCEPT when requesting for enabling bluetooth. However this does not work when  externally disabling bluetooth. When I do that, the Activity does nothing, even if I code the situation in onResume function.

I tried using a boolean to manage those cases, but the onResume function is so fast that it runs before setting any boolean.

This is my Kotlin code for the ScanningForDevicesActivity:

```
class ScanningForDevicesActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityScanningForDevicesBinding

    private var bluetoothWasDenied: Boolean = false

    companion object{
        val BLUETOOTH_REQUEST_CODE = 1
    }

    private val bluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter by lazy {
        val bluetoothManager = getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager
        bluetoothManager.adapter
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scanning_for_devices)

        bluetoothWasDenied = false

        binding = ActivityScanningForDevicesBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)

        if(!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled){
            promptEnableBluetooth()
        }

    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        if(!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled){
            promptEnableBluetooth()
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if(requestCode == BLUETOOTH_REQUEST_CODE){
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED){
                bluetoothWasDenied = true
                val goMainActivityIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(goMainActivityIntent)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun promptEnableBluetooth(){
        if(!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled){
            val enableBluetoothIntent = Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE)
            startActivityForResult(enableBluetoothIntent, BLUETOOTH_REQUEST_CODE)
        }
    }
}
```

P.S: don't mind the bluetoothWasDenied var, I tried to use it but it did not work for what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the permission in manifest file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```

And after that you have to listen changes from broadcast Receiver whenever its switch on and off

```
  private val bluetoothReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        val action = intent?.action
        if (action.equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)) {
            val state = intent?.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, BluetoothAdapter.ERROR)
            when (state) {
                BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF -> {
                }
                BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF -> {
                }
                BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON -> {
                }
                BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON -> {
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

register it onCreate method

```
 fun registerBroadCast(){
    val filter = IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)
    registerReceiver(bluetoothReceiver, filter)
}
```

And finally in onDestroy unregister it

```
override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    unregisterReceiver(bluetoothReceiver)
}
```